# Wear OS Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) not connecting to other device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os, android-bluetooth, android-wear-2.0

I'm working on a Wear OS app that connects to an BLE device. On older Wear OS versions it worked fine. The app could create a connection to the device by it self (the user only needed to confirm the connection). Now on a newer Wear OS version it doesn't work anymore. The app can't create a connection by it self. The user has to open the device settings, connect to the BLE device manually and reopen the app. Than the app has the connection and can communicate with the BLE device.
For example. I tried it with the code of this tutorial:
https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/

I have two Wear OS devices.
One with an older Wear OS Version:

- Modell: Moto 360
- Wear OS by Google: 2.12
- System version: H MR1
- Security update from: January 1. 2020

and one with the newest Wear OS Version:

- Modell: Carlyle HR (Fossil)
- Wear OS by Google: 2.28
- System version: H MR2
- Security update from: February 1. 2021

On the watch with the older version the app can create the BLE connection with the other BLE device by it self. That works fine. The watch with the newer version shows the confirmation window for the user but after that the connection always fails. Here the user has to manually connect to the device and than return to the app.

My supposition is that it is a bug in the Wear OS version. Has one of you the same problem and/or a solution?
Also I would like to downgrade the Wear OS version of the newer watch. Is that possible some how?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance - I could not get a TicWatch Pro 3 GPS or a Samsung Watch 4 (running Wear 3) to connect to a known device until I followed your advice and manually connecting to the device before running the App. Still can't get notifications to work so have settled for timer initiated reads (frustrating)